# Calculate the nth term of a sequence. Why am I getting compiler errors?

Tags: c++, recursion

I will write a program that will calculate the nth term of a sequence defined by the following recurrence relation.

```
S(1) = 2
S(n) = 2*S(n-1) + n*2^n
```

It will ask the user for the value of n, and then do the following statement:

```
cout << "The " << n << "th term is " << findterm(n) << endl;
```

find term will either be a recursive function to determine the value for the nth term.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

long double findterm(long double);
long double in;

int main()
{
    clock_t begin;
    clock_t end;
    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> in;
    begin = clock();
    cout << endl << "The " << in << "th term is " << findterm(in) << endl;
    end = clock();
    cout << (float)((float)end) - ((float)begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " TU." << endl;
    return 0;
}

long double findterm(long double n)
{
    float bn = 1;
    if( n == 1 )
    {
        return 2;
    }
    return((2*findterm(n-1)) + (n*pow(2, (double)n)));
}
```

Why am I getting compiler errors?

```
(6): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
(11): error C2065: 'clock_t' : undeclared identifier
(11): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'begin'
(11): error C2065: 'begin' : undeclared identifier
(11): error C2065: 'end' : undeclared identifier
(17): error C2065: 'begin' : undeclared identifier
(17): error C3861: 'clock': identifier not found
(19): error C2065: 'end' : undeclared identifier
(19): error C3861: 'clock': identifier not found
(21): error C2065: 'end' : undeclared identifier
(21): error C2065: 'begin' : undeclared identifier
(21): error C2065: 'CLOCKS_PER_SEC' : undeclared identifier
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code wont compile is you havent included any standard time-related library
just include **time.h** or **ctime**

```
#include <time.h>
```

This header file contains definitions of functions to get and manipulate date and time information.